# How to get iOS device apps count?

Tags: ios

I am working on to get the total apps count of the User device, Please let me know if somebody has an answer to this Topic.

Comment: let me clear one things here i think you want to know about your ABC app installed count ?

Answer (score 1):

Not (legally) possible. You should familiarize yourself with the guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit